# Gif images not working in ionic-5 splash screen

Tags: ionic4

I want to add gif images in splash screen but it is not wokring. I am using ionic version 5.0.7
Please help if anybody knows.

Answer (score 1):

Better use Lottie for animations in splash-screen.

install:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-lottie-splashscreen
npm install @ionic-native/lottie-splash-screen
```

Code:

```
import { LottieSplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/lottie-splash-screen/ngx';


constructor(private lottieSplashScreen: LottieSplashScreen) { }

...


this.lottieSplashScreen.show('www/lottie/animation.json', false, 1024, 768)
  .then((res: any) => console.log(res))
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
```

See an example [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/lottie-splash-screen)

Comment: A working example without Ionic can be found in the [example folder](https://github.com/timbru31/cordova-plugin-lottie-splashscreen/tree/master/example) on the repo, too.